# Travelling to Berlin Germany from India and would like to Take My Assembled PC (except monitor) with me

Tags: germany, india, berlin

I will soon be travelling on dependant visa with my wife to Berlin and I would like to take my CPU (assembled PC cabinet with keyboard and mouse) with me. Is it possible? visiting Germany for the first time and will be seeking long term residence (also job).

Machine is big can't fit in hand bag and will be a luggage itself.
What kind of problem I will be facing, this will attract any duty?

Comment: @lambshaanxy Seems to be in the other direction.

Comment: Are you moving (i.e. taking up residence) to Berlin? Going back there after a trip to India (i.e. you are already a resident)? Or simply visiting?

Comment: The three problems are airport security, airline baggage rules, and possible import duties. Is it small enough to fit into hand luggage or does it have to go into checked luggage? I wouldn't trust the average airport luggage handler with a pc unless it is properly packaged.

Comment: @Relaxed Whoah! My bad, this may be the first question ever on this site about Customs out of India.

Comment: Will you be bringing the computer back to India at the end of your trip?

Comment: This isn't what you're asking about, but... I would disassemble all the internal components and individually bubble/anti-static wrap them, then pack all the components back into the case and fill the rest with bubble wrap to ensure nothing shifts around. I wouldn't trust edge connectors on any card (video card to mobo, SATA cable to HD, memory, etc) to any sort of shipping, be it airport baggage handlers, UPS, FedEx, DHL, etc. I'd probably even remove the cooler from the CPU, especially if it's a large one. Rebuilding is easier than replacing broken parts.

Comment: I'd probably even dismount/pack any HDDs to ensure that bumps and drops don't bend any mount points. SSDs are probably light enough that they could remain mounted. Any internal cabling could be thrown, er, placed into a bag and put into the case. If there's room, you could pack the keyboard & mouse in the case (more bubble wrap), too.